# Jasmine test for object properties

Tags: javascript, jasmine

What I'd like to do

```
describe('my object', function() {
  it('has these properties', function() {
    expect(Object.keys(myObject)).toEqual([
      'property1',
      'property2',
      ...
    ]);
  });
});
```

but of course `Object.keys` returns an array, which by definition is ordered...I'd prefer to have this test pass regardless of property ordering (which makes sense to me since there is no spec for object key ordering anyway...(at least up to ES5)).

How can I verify my object has all the properties it is supposed to have, while also making sure it isn't missing any properties, without having to worry about listing those properties in the right order?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

It's [built in now](https://jasmine.github.io/api/edge/jasmine.html#.objectContaining)!

```
describe("jasmine.objectContaining", function() {
  var foo;

  beforeEach(function() {
    foo = {
      a: 1,
      b: 2,
      bar: "baz"
    };
  });

  it("matches objects with the expect key/value pairs", function() {
    expect(foo).toEqual(jasmine.objectContaining({
      bar: "baz"
    }));
    expect(foo).not.toEqual(jasmine.objectContaining({
      c: 37
    }));
  });
});
```

Alternatively, you could use external checks like [_.has](http://underscorejs.org/#has) (which wraps `myObject.hasOwnProperty(prop)`):

```
var _ = require('underscore');
describe('my object', function() {
  it('has these properties', function() {
    var props = [
      'property1',
      'property2',
      ...
    ];
    props.forEach(function(prop){
      expect(_.has(myObject, prop)).toBeTruthy();
    })
  });
});
```

Comment: but by the second way the values can't be ignored, right?!

Comment: good point, OP needs first approach for use case of "test keys present without testing values"

Comment: Thumbs up to the `jasmine.objectContaining` part

Comment: The link for `jasmine.objectContaining` in the answer is broken. Here is the [new page](https://jasmine.github.io/api/edge/jasmine.html#.objectContaining).

Comment: @bicarlsen Thank you, updated. Feel free to use the flagging functionality for edit requests like this in case the OP doesn't log in for a while

Answer (score 15):

The simplest solution? Sort.

```
var actual = Object.keys(myObject).sort();
var expected = [
  'property1',
  'property2',
  ...
].sort();

expect(actual).toEqual(expected);
```

Answer (score 13):

```
it('should contain object keys', () => {
  expect(Object.keys(myObject)).toContain('property1');
  expect(Object.keys(myObject)).toContain('property2');
  expect(Object.keys(myObject)).toContain('...');
});
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Code-only answers are not considered to be good quality. Please elaborate what your code does and how it helps to resolve the issue.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 4):

I ended up here because I was looking for a way to check that an object had a particular subset of properties.
I started with `_.has` or `Object.hasOwnProperties` but the output of `Expected false to be truthy` when it failed wasn't very useful.

Using underscore's intersection gave me a better expected/actual output

```
  var actualProps = Object.keys(myObj); // ["foo", "baz"]
  var expectedProps =["foo","bar"];
  expect(_.intersection(actualProps, expectedProps)).toEqual(expectedProps);
```

In which case a failure might look more like
`Expected [ 'foo' ] to equal [ 'foo', 'bar' ]`

Answer (score 0):

Here are some new possible solutions too:

- There's a module for that: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-object-matchers
- With ES2016, you can use a map and convert the object to a map too

Answer (score 0):

I prefer use this; becouse, you have more possibilities to be execute indivual test.

```
import AuthRoutes from '@/router/auth/Auth.ts';

describe('AuthRoutes', () => {
    it('Verify that AuthRoutes be an object', () => {
        expect(AuthRoutes instanceof Object).toBe(true);
    });

    it("Verify that authroutes in key 'comecios' contains expected key", () => {
        expect(Object.keys(AuthRoutes.comercios)).toContain("path");
        expect(Object.keys(AuthRoutes.comercios)).toContain("component");
        expect(Object.keys(AuthRoutes.comercios)).toContain("children");
        expect(AuthRoutes.comercios.children instanceof Array).toBe(true);

        // Convert the children Array to Object for verify if this contains the spected key
        let childrenCommerce = Object.assign({}, AuthRoutes.comercios.children);
        expect(Object.keys(childrenCommerce[0])).toContain("path");
        expect(Object.keys(childrenCommerce[0])).toContain("name");
        expect(Object.keys(childrenCommerce[0])).toContain("component");
        expect(Object.keys(childrenCommerce[0])).toContain("meta");

        expect(childrenCommerce[0].meta instanceof Object).toBe(true);
        expect(Object.keys(childrenCommerce[0].meta)).toContain("Auth");
        expect(Object.keys(childrenCommerce[0].meta)).toContain("title");

    })
});
```

Answer (score -2):

I am late to this topic but there is a a method that allows you to check if an object has a property or key/value pair:

```
expect(myObject).toHaveProperty(key);
expect({"a": 1, "b":2}).toHaveProperty("a");
```

or

```
expect(myObject).toHaveProperty(key,value);
expect({"a": 1, "b":2}).toHaveProperty("a", "1");
```

Comment: I'm not seeing the `toHaveProperty()` method.  Is this for jasmine?

Comment: That method is not available for Jasmine