# Jasmine test for local property

Tags: angular, object, jasmine

I'm not able to apply objectContaining which is accepted as an answer in this question:
[Jasmine test for object properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31528200/jasmine-test-for-object-properties)
since I don't have a global object.

My setup is:
When the user clicks a button onApplyFilter() is called and puts together a local Object called filterReady. The propertyvalues are taken from the class globally. It then passes this property to another function.

```
onApplyFilter() {
    const filterReady = new Filter();
    filterReady.maxCount = this.maxCount;
    filterReady.language = this.language;
    filterReady.ids = this.ids;
    this.sendFilterReady(filterReady);
  }
```

I know how to test if sendFilterReady was called with a mock, but does it make sense to write another test for putting filterReady together? And how should a test for this look like?

Comment: If you already test that `sendFilterReady` has been called with (hint: `.toHaveBeenCalledWith(expectedParams)`), then you implicitly check that `filterReady` was mapped correctly.

Comment: Do the coverage, it all branches are already covered - then there is small-to-no-point of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Because `this.sendFilterReady` is part of your class the best wait is not to spy it, but to spy a service it calls (httpClient for example).

for example

```js
sendFilterReady(filter) {
  this.http.get('blabla', filter);
}
```

then you could assert like that

```js
const spy = spyOne(httpClient, 'get');
obj.onApplyFilter();

const expected = new Filter();
expected.maxCount = 123;
expected.language = 'en';
expected.ids = [1, 2, 3];
expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expected);
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. Since I do test if all properties are set correctly, I decided to not check if filterReady is set correctly, too, since it sounds quite conclusive that a good coverage makes this test redundant

Comment: yep, the right way would be to test side effects, because sendFilterReady can unset / change properties and the test doesn't make sense anymore. So the right way would be to test that an input causes an output, but what happened with the input in the middle - isn't important.